# Generate an autoincrement number and insert data to Oracle DB using EntityManager NativeQuery

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

I am developing an ETL application using Spring. I have the data to be inserted in String type and want to load the data using entityManager.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate()
I do not have any entity here as the ETL application can be used for any datasource.

To demonstrate the problem:

The source data can be any valid JSON like `{name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York"}`

The application itself generates the INSERT query from here like:
`INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME (Name, Age, City) values ('John',31,'New York')`

I am using an `@PersistenceContext EntityManager em` to connect to Oracle 12c. Thus, running 
em.createNativeQuery(query).executeUpdate does the job for me.

However, when I try to use an own index within the target table, I am not able o figure out the correct method of doing so.

I tried using KeyHolder class, but it works with JdbcTemplate and not EntityManager

```
KeyHolder keyHolder = new GeneratedKeyHolder();
```

I am unable to use

```
em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil().getIdentifier(entity);
```

as I can't create an entity here.

What would be the correct mehtod of creating an own unique key here?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend switching to `JdbcTemplate` since it doesn't look like you are using any of the features of JPA anyway.

If you insist on using the `EntityManager`, I think you'll have to select the sequence number first using `SELECT my_seq.nextval FROM DUAL` and then use that for the insert statement.

Comment: Using nextval sequence returns the sequence starting value everytime as the query is not persited to the database immediately. in my case, it is always 0.

Comment: Then something really strange is going on. Because `nextval` is the pseudo column do get the next value of a sequence and should never return the same value twice as long as you don't wrap around or reset your sequence. See also: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm